# DataTables 1.10.6 with ajax, requested unknown parameter 0 for row 0

Tags: ajax, django, datatables

I'm new to using DataTables and I had it working fine until I wanted to switch to server-side processing.

It feels like I'm starting to get close to it working, it now gives me an error and displays the right amount of rows but without any data.

So I get the error:

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-outputTest - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. Fore more information about this error, please see https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#dataTables-outputTest').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/TestData/data-source"
    });
});
```

This is the JSON I'm trying to put into the table:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "cycle_p": 628320,
            "designation": "C1",
            "gear": "R660",
            "cycle_k": 204000,
            "reportnr": "NA05006"
        }
    ],
    "draw": "1",
    "recordsFiltered": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 1
}
```

Don't know if it matters but I'm using Django and the output is a mix of attributes from different models.

And here are the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-outputTest">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Report</th>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Gear</th>
            <th>Cycle K</th>
            <th>Cycle P</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Would really appreciate some help since the database has to be able to grow quite a lot without slowing everything down.

Comment: Okay so I removed some things in the html when I cleaned it to post here. So i got rid of that error message. Now I'm stuck on processing instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which data corresponds to which columns :

```
$('#dataTables-outputTest').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/TestData/data-source",
    columns : [
       { data : "cycle_p" },
       { data : "destination" },
       { data : "gear" },
       { data : "cycle_k" },
       { data : "reportnr" }
    ]
});
```

This will produce rows with `<td>`'s in the order they are declared in columns. If you have another layout, and / or additionally `<td>`'s that not  should receive data from the JSON, you can use `columnDefs` instead :

```
columnDefs : [
   { data : "cycle_p", targets : 0 },
   { data : "destination", targets : 8  },
   { data : "gear", targets : 3  },
   { data : "cycle_k", targets : 2  },
   { data : "reportnr", targets : 1  }
]
```

where target is the column index.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but managed to fix it by just reordering them. But It's a good tip and I might need it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You're using [Objects](http://datatables.net/manual/data#Objects) in your data, therefore you need to match object properties to table columns using [columns.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data). See the example below:

```
$('#dataTables-outputTest').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/TestData/data-source",
    "columns": [
       { "data": "cycle_p" },
       { "data": "designation" },
       { "data": "gear" },
       { "data": "cycle_k" },
       { "data": "reportnr" }
    ]
});
```